# why NPOI excel textboxes share same textvalues?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, apache-poi, npoi

I created 3 different textboxes in my excel work sheet

```
 XSSFDrawing drawing = (XSSFDrawing)activeWorkSheet.CreateDrawingPatriarch();
 IClientAnchor anchor1= drawing.CreateAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, left1, top1, right1, bottom1);
 IClientAnchor anchor2= drawing.CreateAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, left2, top2, right2, bottom2);
 IClientAnchor anchor3= drawing.CreateAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, left3, top3, right3, bottom3);

XSSFTextBox textbox1= drawing.CreateTextbox(anchor1);
XSSFTextBox textbox2= drawing.CreateTextbox(anchor2);
XSSFTextBox textbox3= drawing.CreateTextbox(anchor3);
```

and set their values using:

```
textbox1.setTitle(title1);
textbox2.setTitle(title2);
textbox3.setTitle(title3);
```

I want different values in my textboxes but in the output these text boxes share the same value, ie the last value given.
If setTitle method is not called for textbox 3, all the textboxes share textbox2's value. 
If setTitle method is not called for textbox 2 & 3, all the textboxes share textbox1's value. 
Even if these textboxes are in different sheet, all of them have common  value for their content(that of the last modified one).

So how can i have textboxes with unique values in my excel sheet?

Comment: `XSSFTextBox.setTitle`? Which NPOI version are you using?

Comment: @AxelRichter v2.2.1.0